# how to get user confirmation before committing insert in database using Servlet and JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to confirm Insertion of data in database from user before committing it.

InsertData.java Servlet to insert data in database is as follows:

```
public class InsertData extends HttpServlet {
private PrintWriter out;
private String M_ID;
private String E_MERC_ID;
private String C_ID;
private String B_ID;
private String M_ID;
private char P3_STATUS;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public InsertData() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    String T_DATE_TIME = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println(T_DATE_TIME);
    String E_TXN_REF_NO = request.getParameter("E_TXN_REF_NO");
    String T_REF_NO = request.getParameter("T_REF_NO");
    String E_TXN_AMOUNT = request.getParameter("E_TXN_AMOUNT");
    M_ID = "VODAESP";
    E_MERC_ID = "VODATUPMU1";
    C_ID = "am418785";
    B_ID = "CIT";
    M_ID = "123456";
    P_STATUS = 'Y';
    try {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.23.34.4:1521:abc";

        // Database credentials
        final String USER = "abc";
        final String PASS = "abc";
        // Step 1. Load the JDBC driver
        Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        // Step 2. Create a Connection object
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("got connection");

        // // Step 4. Use the same Statement object to obtain a ResultSet
        // object
        String sql = "INSERT INTO E2_PAYMENT"
                + "(E_TXN_REF_NO,M_ID,E_MERC_ID,C_ID,"
                + "T_REF_NO,B_ID,M_ID,T_DATE_TIME,E_TXN_AMOUNT,P_STATUS)"
                + " values('" + E_TXN_REF_NO + "','" + M_ID + "','"
                + E_MERC_ID + "','" + C_ID + "','" + T_REF_NO
                + "','" + B_ID + "','" + M_ID + "',TO_DATE('"
                + T_DATE_TIME + "','YYYY-MM-DD'),'" + E_TXN_AMOUNT
                + "','" + 3_STATUS + "')";

        s.executeUpdate(sql);
        s.close();
        con.close();
        // request.setAttribute("con", con);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("RetriveData").forward(request,
                response);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // JDBC driver class not found, print error message to the console
        System.out.println(e1.toString());
        out.println(e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // Exception when executing java.sql related commands, print error
        // message to the console
        System.out.println(e2.toString());
        out.println(e2.toString());
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        // other unexpected exception, print error message to the console
        System.out.println(e3.toString());
        out.println(e3.toString());
        e3.printStackTrace();

    }
}}
```

I want to commit this query after User Confirmation need Help?

Comment: Why dont you ask before running logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should ask confirmation before going to server not at a point before coming
It does not make sense to first do the processing
on server and then come back to client for confirmation which you can do in single go

I would recommend using [jconfirm](http://riggerthegeek.github.io/jConfirm/)

Answer (score 2):

On your page you may just add something like that;

```
onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?')"
```

Answer (score 1):

First do navigate to confirmation page and then, if user confirms, execute insertData.java